# Dismissing ViewController Shifts View of Parent Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiimageview

My app looks like this when you launch it:

[image]

On every row except for the top one, I can push a new view controller, and dismiss it, and everything stays the same.  However, if I click the Instagram row, and then dismiss the view that is pushed onto it, my screen looks like this:
[image]

In the Instagram controller that is pushed, the `viewDidLoad` looks like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"Instagram";
    UIBarButtonItem *theButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Post" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(doit)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = theButton;
    self.downloading = YES;
    self.mediaArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[SBInstagramCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"SBInstagramCell"];
    [self.collectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionReusableView class] forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter withReuseIdentifier:@"footer"];

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    self.multipleLastEntities = [NSArray array];

    self.instagramController = [SBInstagramController instagramControllerWithMainViewController:self];
    self.instagramController.isSearchByTag = self.isSearchByTag;
    self.instagramController.searchTag = self.searchTag;
    [self downloadNext];

    self.collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = YES;
    refreshControl_ = [[SBInstagramRefreshControl alloc] initInScrollView:self.collectionView];
    [refreshControl_ addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshCollection:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    loaded_ = YES;

    [self showSwitch];

    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:nil];

}
```

I get to this view like this:

```
SBInstagramController *instagram = [SBInstagramController instagram];


        instagram.showOnePicturePerRow = YES; //to change way to show the feed, one picture per row(default = NO)

        instagram.showSwitchModeView = YES; //show a segment controller with view option

        [instagram refreshCollection]; //refresh instagram feed

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:instagram.feed animated:YES];
```

To me, it looks like the UIImageView is being shifted down about 44 pixels, which would be the space of a Navigation Bar, I just can't understand why it would be doing that.  I use `AutoLayout` and have both the `UITableView` and the `UIImageView` pinned to the top superview, but it is only the UIImageView that moves.

Comment: Show your image view constraints. There are some problems with them.

Comment: Found the issue.  The Instagram view controller had navigationBar setTranslucent to NO in order to have a segment bar attached.  Setting that to yes on viewWillDisappear took care of the problem.  No issues at all with my constraints.